# How can I show a message for few seconds then redirect to another route in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to perform an asyncronous function call that returns a `Promise`. On successful response I want to show a message for 5 seconds then redirect to another route.

I am using function components. Since I can not use `useEffect` in a function how can I use `setTimeout` method to do that task.

```js
async function handleResetPassword(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    setMessage("");
    await passwordResetEmail(emailRef.current.value);
    setTimeout(navigate("/login"), 5000);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    setMessage("Failed to send password reset email");
  }
        
  setMessage("Check your inbox and follow the instruction in email");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the code is immediately calling `navigate` and passing the result of calling it to `setTimeout`.

```js
setTimeout(
  navigate("/login"), // <-- navigate called immediately!!
  5000
);
```

It should instead pass a *callback* function that calls `navigate`.

```js
setTimeout(() => navigate("/login"), 5000);
```

Or pass the `navigate` function *as* the callback and pass the `"/login"` path as an argument later when the callback is invoked.

```js
setTimeout(navigate, 5000, "/login");
```

If you want to *actually* redirect to `"/login"` then the code should also pass `replace: true` in the `options` argument.

```js
setTimeout(() => navigate("/login", { replace: true }), 5000);
```

```js
setTimeout(navigate, 5000, "/login", { replace: true });
```